# How to perform a step to next source available in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

While debbuging a java application, I usually get "Source not found." when there is no source available for my current location. How can I jump to next source available ? Is there any button or shortcut ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use **step filters** to skip the packages of the library you have only in binary  or just don't want to step through a framework like spring which heavily uses proxies.

```
Menu: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering
```

Documentation

```
Menu: Help -> Help contents -> Java development user guide > Reference > Views > Debug View
```

Select the Use Step Filters command [  ] to change whether step filters should be used in the Debug View. You can also use the keyboard shortcut Shift+F5.

Step filters are commonly used to filter out types that you do not wish to see or step through while debugging.